# Possible to adjust tile layout halfway though?

Tags: bathroom, tile, layout, porcelain

tiling a 100 sqft bathroom with 12x24 porcelain tile. I am about 1/3rd done and called it quits for the day. I used a laser level but I think I messed up or it shifted (first time tiling anything) and my vertical line (from the perspective of coming in the bathroom) is just a tiny fraction of a hair off. I doubt anyone would notice but I do. I am also concerned with how it will mate up to the transition.

Is it possible to start tomorrow and just barely shift the layout back to square? It would result in (hopefully) imperceptibly different grout sizes for a few of them as I get back to the correct line.

Would that make it worse than just finishing it as is and dealing with it at the transition?  Thanks!

EDIT: Added pic of the actual squared off line against my current grout line.

[image]

Comment: please add a picture, and remember the flaws you see today might be gone in 6 months

Comment: Unless it's grotesque, no one will notice but you.

Comment: Good places to adjust slightly are behind/around sink units, toilets, inside showers, around baths, door jambs, window reveals. Maybe true u the line over a couple of tile rows, rather than all in one go.

Comment: A laser can be deceiving on a floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finish laying out the rest of the tiles without the Thinset, using the spacers as you've done so far. You can/should even cut the transition tiles so you get the complete picture. Then jockey them around to see if getting back on the right line makes a difference. You will probably realize it doesn't make much difference but that will be your call. Shifting large tiles can sometimes backfire on you down the road unless you lay them all out first.

Comment: Thanks Jack!  I dry fit everything else and it will only be crooked by like 1/16th of an inch against the transition.  I mortared all of the full cut tiles down today and aside from one grout like that is closer to 1/4", it all looks good. Appreciate it!